# Catching HTTP answer to external file from batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I started to write my batch file (let's name main.bat), which runs different bat files in different locations (a.bat, b.bat, c.bat...).
The main.bat is like this:

```
echo off 

chdir /d D:\batch\a-folder
call a.bat

chdir /d D:\batch\b-folder
call b.bat
...
```

And the a.bat, b.bat, c.bat... have cURL links, which usually answers 200 OK

Is it possible to catch which batch files did not received 200 OK (The most important is 500) and save the name of the batch file or anything in the external file?

I followed issue with creating a file with the names of files stored in the folder, but I couldn't find any idea to save the HTTP response

Comment: You have to test whether `cURL` sets `errorlevel` variable if the request was successful or not, then check for that value and write to the external file.

Comment: OK, I'll follow that path, thanks for response :)

Comment: at least give an example of the code inside the batch files, then I could help, for now it is not possible to suggest something not known.

Comment: The `a.bat` and `b.bat` scripts should return an exit code. `EXIT /B ?` If `curl` does not set ERRORLEVEL, then you need to parse the output to see if it received a successful result. If not, then `EXIT /B 7` or something other than 0.